# Are Laptop Cooling Fans That Suck Hot Air From Vent Effective?

Tags: laptop, temperature, cooling-pad, fan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Laptop Cooling Accessories (Pads, external fans, etc.) Effective?](https://superuser.com/questions/321407/are-laptop-cooling-accessories-pads-external-fans-etc-effective)

I am not talking about **[cooling pads](http://images.bestbuy.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/9943/9943834_sa.jpg)**, but cooling fans like these:
[image]

Comment: Boris, please update your first question rather than asking a second one.

Comment: Where doee's this connect to the laptop. Do you just put it close to the exhaust vent? Links would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Anything that would increase airflow through the laptop will help reduce temperatures of the hardware, whether this device is effective at doing this, who knows, unless there is a reputable review out there somewhere.